# Is there a better way to do this command to find strings in a file excluding special characters?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

Is there a better way to do this command to find strings in a file excluding special characters?

Currently I'm doing:

```
strings file.abc | grep -v \= | grep -v \] | grep -v \) | more
```

I'd like to add more special characters so I'm only getting a-z and A-Z in the results.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to exclude these special characters you can use regular expressions (e.g., [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) like this:

```
strings file.abc | grep -Pv "[=\])]"
```

If you want to display only strings containing some specific characters, you could use grep *instead of* strings.

The command

```
grep -Poa "[A-Za-z]{4,}" file.abc
```

shows all words with of at least four letters.

Here:

- The `-o` switch makes grep show only the match (rather than the entire line).
- The `-a` switch forces treating a binary file as a text file.
- The PCRE `[A-Za-z]{4,}` matches four or more consecutive letters.

  Four is the default number that *strings* uses. Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
strings file.abc | grep '^[A-Za-z]*$'
```

?

That will give you only lines consisting only of letters.

Actually, you probably want lines containing only one or more *sequences* of letters;
i.e., lines containing letters and spaces.  If that’s what you want, do

```
strings file.abc | grep '^[A-Za-z ]*$'
```

with a space after the `z`. 
If you decide that you want to include any other characters, put them inside the brackets. 
(Warning: some characters will be tricky,
such as the quote character itself, `'`, and the right bracket, `]`.)